# Grounding a soldering iron and it's enclosure

Tags: esd, enclosure, grounding

So, I assembled a soldering iron kit and put the control unit in an aluminum enclosure and intend to use a  [Mean Well SP-240 24V](https://www.meanwell.co.uk/media/productPDF/SP-240-SPEC.PDF) power supply with it. I just wanted to verify a couple of things. The tip should be connected to chassis ground via a  1MΩ resistor and chassis ground should be connected to the Mean Well's FG (mains earth), right? To be clear, power/signal ground are seperate from chassis ground in this system and it's only the latter I'm referring to.

[not sure if it matters but this is Sweden, mains 230V/50Hz, PSU is 24V 240W (~10A), soldering iron is 24V 70W (~3A)]

Comment: That is correct for ESD control and your Ohm meter can verify this.

Comment: @Tony Stewart this would do as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct for ESD control and your Ohm meter can verify this